# Function for selecting even numbers in a vector in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I want to create a function that, given a vector, reports another vector with the even numbers.

```
evens <- function(x){
  vector <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (i %% 2 == 0){
      vector[i] <- vector[i] + i
    }
  }
  vector
}
```

But this gives  `NULL` for a number in x.

Anybody knows what´s missing?
Thanks

Comment: `x[ x %% 2 == 0]` is a one-shot for reducing a vector of numbers `x` into the values that are "even". Two things wrong with your code: `i %% 2 == 0` is testing whether the *index* of your number is even, not the number itself, you might want `x[i] %% 2 == 0`. Second, your first `vector[i]` is `NA`, so adding that to any number will always be `NA`; plus you are not guaranteed to have an output of `length(x)`, so assigning to `vector[i]` is problematic to begin with. Consider keeping track of how many elements you've added to `vector` separately from `i`.

Comment: On that last note, I mean `j <- 0; for (i in 1:length(x)) { if (...) { j <- j + 1; vector[j] <- x[i]; } }; vector` or something similar.

Comment: A short and maybe *fast* version to get the *even numbers* from x is `x[!x%%2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**
You will be better of using apply functions which are usually faster and more user friendly. In your case it will be:

```
some_array <- c(1,4,5,7,8)
some_array[lapply(some_array, "%%", 2) == 0]
```

The above code will apply modulus over 2 function to your array and return only the elements which satisfy modulus over 2 == 0 condition.

**Solution 2**
If you still want to use your approach then the mistake is that you calculate the reminder (and respectively append to array) for the index (i.e. `i`). Instead, you should do that for the element of an array (i.e. `x[i]`).
The correct code will be:

```
evens <- function(x){
  vector <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i] %% 2 == 0){ #this was the first error line
      vector <- c(vector, x[i]) ##this was the seconds error line
    }
  }
  vector
}
```

Comment: `lapply` is really over-engineering doing "math" on a vector. (So is a `for` loop, admittedly, but homework is homework.) Beware (in general) that "growing objects", i.e., iteratively appending to vectors (and lists and frames) scales poorly in the long run; c.f., chapter 2 of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), titled "Growing Objects".

Answer (score 10):

I think you could simplify this and speed it up quite a lot:

```r
evens <- function(x) subset(x, x %% 2 == 0)
evens(1:10)
#> [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Using `lapply` probably isn't a great idea since it actually uses loops under the hood. Best to stick to R's native vectorization, as you can see from the following benchmark:

```
evens1 <- function(some_array) some_array[lapply(some_array, "%%", 2) == 0]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(evens1(1:10000), evens(1:10000))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>             expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#>  evens1(1:10000) 5694.309 5883.195 6359.1855 6039.232 6306.992 14811.840   100   b
#>   evens(1:10000)  757.942  770.944  788.6802  785.317  799.346   912.267   100  a
```

Answer (score 3):

A short and maybe *fast* way to get the *even numbers* from `x` is `x[!x%%2]`.

```
evens.HrantDavtyan <- function(x) x[lapply(x, "%%", 2) == 0]
evens.HrantDavtyan2 <- function(x){
  vector <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i] %% 2 == 0){ #this was the first error line
      vector <- c(vector, x[i]) ##this was the seconds error line
    }
  }
  vector
}
evens.AllanCameron <- function(x) subset(x, x %% 2 == 0)
evens.r2evans <- function(x) x[ x %% 2 == 0]
evens.GKi <- function(x) x[!x%%2]
x <- 1:10000
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(evens.HrantDavtyan(x), evens.HrantDavtyan2(x), evens.AllanCameron(x), evens.r2evans(x), evens.GKi(x), control=list(order="block"))
#Unit: microseconds
#                   expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  evens.HrantDavtyan(x)  3163.272  3222.8030  3938.6202  3269.1015  3527.5345 33867.486   100
# evens.HrantDavtyan2(x) 26009.475 28061.4230 28196.7498 28275.5705 28794.2855 30856.206   100
#  evens.AllanCameron(x)   239.599   240.4480   257.7027   240.9265   243.7575  1715.947   100
#       evens.r2evans(x)   199.506   200.2945   202.1106   200.7690   203.7865   224.104   100
#           evens.GKi(x)   191.303   191.7400   193.2737   192.1310   193.2295   217.001   100
```

Comment: Since we don't have deviation/variance, it's hard to say if your solution's speed is *statistically different* than mine ;-) (I'm guessing that it is, guessing by using iqr as a proxy for a t-test)

Comment: @r2evans all of GKi's 100 evaluations were faster than your median, so it would definitely be statistically significant if you used a Mann-Whitney. Of course, both of you are significantly faster than me: my results don't even overlap with yours...

Comment: Allan, it was mostly sarcasm, squeezing water from a rock. Yes, it's faster, and it even wins by code-golf! I would not have thought to use `subset`, but yours is not trailing by much. \*shrug\* Either way, yes :-)